# Why point closeness is differing from scatter plot to hexbin plot?

Tags: d3.js

Please look at Hexbin and scatterplots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvJXv.jpg

Why in Hexbinplot, points donot touch each other whereas in scatterplot it clearly touches the close points ?

I expected my hexbin plot comes up like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145 but it didnot.

I am using d3.hexbin plugin.

The only code that is differing from Hexbin plot to scatter plot (I am dealing with same dataset) apart from little bit of scaling is:

For Hexbin:

```
 var color = d3.scale.linear()
                .range(["white", "steelblue"])
                .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab);

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
               .extent([[0,0],[size - padding , padding]])
               .radius();

hexbin.x(function(d,i){return x(subdata[0][i]);})
hexbin.y(function(d,i){return y(subdata[0][i]);})

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "mesh")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", size);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .selectAll(".hexagon")
    .data(hexbin(datum))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

For scatterplot:

```
 svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(datum)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.style("fill", "steelblue")
.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
    return x(subdata[0][i]);
})
.attr("cy", function (d,i) {
    return y(subdata[0][i]);
})
.attr("r", 3)
```

Where am i doing wrong ?

Edit1: Included some fraction of code under Hexbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set...

```
.attr("d", hexbin.hexagon(5))
//radius value here ------^
```

..., the hexagons will touch only if you set the same value in the hexabin generator:

```
var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .radius(5)//same value here
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);
```

According to your result, I believe that was not the case. Thus, the solution can be simply removing that value:

```
.attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
//no radius here --------^
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, It still didnot change even after making the specified changes. I will edit the code that includes radius part too. I am using d3 version 3

Comment: You have to set the radius in your `var hexabin`.

Comment: yes, i did. I changed radius in var hexbin to radius(10) and in .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon(10))....And, i tried different other combinations...May be i am doing wrong somewhere else in the code...?

Comment: Probably. The best idea is creating a working code, using fiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever.

Comment: i created a dummy dataset here: https://jsfiddle.net/data_x/5L2hf0zx/46/ and it showed me a weird error of hexbin.x is not a function which i did not got when i tested in ide...i think i am doing wrong here....i am currently working on this...thank you,